# "Capture of ?" error when injecting a bean with unknown type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, generics

I have to inject a bean with an unknown type which is defined as below:

```
@Bean 
public TestService<?> testService() {
    return new DefaultTestServiceImpl();
}
```

where the details of the above classes are:

```
public interface TestService<T extends Info> {
    void insert(T info) throws Exception;
}

public class DefaultTestServiceImpl implements TestService<Info> {
    void insert(Info info) throws Exception;
}
```

I used the following to inject the bean:

```
private final TestService<?> testService;
```

I tried to call the method in my service as below:

```
Info info = new Info();
testService.insert(info);
```

However, IDEA suggests the error "Capture of ?" at "insert(info)". I tried many ways to figure it out, but could not get an answer. Could anyone help?

Comment: why not declare it as `TestService<Info>`? Or please explain why you have to use `TestService<?>`

Comment: That is out of my control. The bean is from a dependency. @Lino Also, if I inject it as TestService<Info>, compile will fail cause the compiler cannot find such bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the compiler complains is because it cannot confirm the type-safety of the operation. There is no way for the compiler to know what argument type is supposed to be given to the `insert` method due to the wildcard being used.

As a possible solution, you can try casting `testService` to an appropriately typed object before calling its methods. For example,

```
TestService<Info> castedTestService = (TestService<Info>) testService;
Info info = new Info();
castedTestService.insert(info);
```